# WP Loop Geo + jQuery .hide() not working correctly

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, loops, advanced-custom-fields

I have a WP loop where each post has a collection of 4 country based images (using ACF).

I only would like to output 1 image per country, however it is displaying all of 4 images per post.

```
<?php
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'quick_links', 'posts_per_page' => 3 );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
   $image_au = get_field("au_image");
   $image_nz = get_field("nz_image");
   $image_us = get_field("us_image");
   $image_gl = get_field("global_image"); //default image 
?>
<script type="text/javascript">

var image_au = <?php echo json_encode($image_au['url']); ?>;
var image_nz = <?php echo json_encode($image_nz['url']); ?>;
var image_us = <?php echo json_encode($image_us['url']); ?>;
var image_gl = <?php echo json_encode($image_gl['url']); ?>;

jQuery.get("http://ipinfo.io", function (response) {
   if (response.country === "AU"){
      jQuery("#resultQLAU").show();
      jQuery("#resultQLNZ").hide();
      jQuery("#resultQLUS").hide();
      jQuery("#resultQLGlobal").hide();
   } else if(response.country === "NZ"){
      jQuery("#resultQLNZ").show();
      jQuery("#resultQLAU").hide();
      jQuery("#resultQLUS").hide();
      jQuery("#resultQLGlobal").hide();
   } else if(response.country === "US"){
      jQuery("#resultQLUS").show();
      jQuery("#resultQLNZ").hide();
      jQuery("#resultQLAU").hide();
      jQuery("#resultQLGlobal").hide();
   } else {
      jQuery("#resultQLGlobal").show();
      jQuery("#resultQLNZ").hide();
      jQuery("#resultQLUS").hide();
      jQuery("#resultQLAU").hide();
   }
   if(image_au === "" && image_nz === "" && image_us === "" && image_gl !== ""){
      jQuery("#resultQLGlobal").show();
   }
}, "jsonp");
</script>
<?php
    echo '<div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6" style="padding:2px">';
    echo '<a href="' . get_field('page_url') . '" class="portfolio-box">';
?>
<div id="resultQLAU">
<img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo $image_au['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image_au['alt']; ?>" />
</div>
<div id="resultQLNZ">
<img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo $image_nz['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image_nz['alt']; ?>" />
</div>
<div id="resultQLUS">
<img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo $image_us['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image_us['alt']; ?>" />
</div>
<div id="resultQLGlobal">
<img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo $image_gl['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image_gl['alt']; ?>" />
</div>
<?php
echo '<div class="portfolio-box-caption">';
echo '<div class="portfolio-box-caption-content">';
echo '<div class="project-category text-faded">' . get_the_title() . '</div>';
echo '<div class="project-name">' . get_the_content() . '</div>';
echo '</div>';
echo '</div>';
echo '</a>';
echo '<h6 class="news-title text-center"><a href="' . get_field('page_url') . '">' . get_the_title() . '<span style=""> <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i></span></a></h6>';
echo '</div>';
endwhile;
?>
```

I originally had the code e.g `<div id="resultQLAU" style="display:none">` and just had `jQuery("#resultQLAU").show();` in script which outputed only the first 
 GEO image of the first post (so GEO was working correct for that 1 post)
Not sure what problem is?

Your help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using **ID** inside your loop so all the block will have the same ids which isn't good as id need to be unique. You may change this by adding a suffix/prefix depending the iteration and use classes instead.

1) add a new var the increment inside your loop like this :

```
$i = 0
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
$i++;
```

2) for each id append the content of $i, for example :

```
jQuery(".resultQLAU_<?php echo $i; ?>").show();
```

do this everywhere you have the id.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately i cannot get this working

Comment: Instead I made the ID into a class and works, thank you for the segue!

Comment: great, am updating my anwser then ;) Classes is always better then ID